# Flutter cannot install app on iPhone after upgrade to iOS 13.1 and Xcode 11

Tags: flutter, ios13, xcode11

Today I had this great idea to update my iPhone to iOS 13 and Xcode to version 11... (why not go for a cup f tea instead?!?)

So now I am not anymore able to install my app developed in flutter in my iPhone. Here is the log

```
2019-09-27 14:10:46.945 ios-deploy[8xxx2:9xxx95] [ !! ] Error 0xe800007f: Device doesn't support wireless sync. AMDeviceStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), &gdbfd, NULL)
Could not install build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on f7xxx37xxxxb5299ef.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on xxx's iPhone.
```

If I run the app using Xcode it works fine but flutter does not work

I have seen this [page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37699) where I think they are talking about the same problem but I am unsure of what I need to do to resolve...

Is there any expert who can suggest what to do ?? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running from `flutter` after a successful launch from xcode? I faced similar problem but with symbols. After a successful xcode launch (wihch populated required symbols), it works good with `flutter`. Your problem might be different.

Comment: `flutter clean` helped me, but after several launching issue still occurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**
The fix has now hit stable release. To update:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37699#issuecomment-537117087

Comment: I see thanks, so then what I need to know is to wait for the new release of flutter... is there any view on when this can happen? ie days or months or years???

Comment: @mactrix I'd suggest you follow the GitHub thread, where this exact question has been asked. You will get more up-to-date information there.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37699

Comment: Sadly this is the only solution. you have to upgrade flutter

Answer (score 2):

**Use a Non-Personal Team provisioning profile Instead of Personal Team.**

Then run on a real iOS device running 13.3 or lower.

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48035

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing but the other answers didn't help me at all,
apparently it happened to me because I had too many app in development on the iPhone.

So my solution was to delete old apps I didn't need anymore and it worked like a charm.